# Apple APP store will not accept my current password

Tags: password, ios, mac-appstore, apple-id

I recently decided to revive an old phone to use around the house on wifi when my current phone is charging. I set the phone up fine with my Apple ID and password, but when I went to go to the App store, it prompted me for my Apple ID and password. I entered it over 7 times, making sure each time that it was indeed correct, however I am still being refused  access.

The only solution I am  offered in this circumstance is to reset the password, but I haven't actually forgotten my password, its just this one device that wont allow me to use it for the App store.

Why does my password work just fine to log into Apple services elsewhere, but not on the App Store on this old phone I would really appreciate it.

running IOS 8.1.1. on an Apple Iphone 4!

EDIT- As a workaround, I wiped the phone to try and start over. Again though, it still will not accept my password for the App store.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to log into the Itunes store with my password, but there was an extra step that was not explained. I had to speak with a friend who told me that when a code comes up on another device that users need to add this code AFTER their passcode in the same field. For example:

if my password was **WaterBedLou**
and the code that was sent to my other device was: **292 399**
I would need to enter: **WaterBedLou292399**

I am glad this worked, but wished there was some explanation of this during the process of trying to log in. Hopefully this answer helps anyone else with the same issue.

Comment: That workaround is only necessary on iOS versions too old to understand 2-factor authentication. Newer phones would give you a pop-up for the number. I guess it can't explain it to you because it doesn't actually know what should be happening.

Comment: @Tetsujin that sounds like what is going on and is a reasonable hypothesis. The last guy who cane along with his 2 cents told me 'I lost' because I refused to change my password while I was simply trying to figure out what was happening. In any case, the phone is so old it wont even update from iOS 8 to 9.3.6. It just hangs.